# Certificate does not have a name

Tags: iis, iis-7, ssl-certificate, certificate

I've installed an SSL certificate in IIS, however the 'Name' column is showing as blank even though I entered a friendly name. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Is this a self signed certificate?

Comment: @Vivek no it's not - does this make a difference?

Comment: which site did you get the certificate from?

Comment: @GMitch I got it from [RapidSSL](http://rapidssl.com)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is how you can change the friendly name (maybe there is a better & quicker way, but I only know this one):

1. Run **mmc.exe**
2. **File | Add/Remove Snap-in...**
3. Select **Certificates** and click "Add"
4. in new pop-up window choose **Computer account** and click "Next"
5. choose **Local Computer** and click "Finish"
6. now "OK"
7. On a left-side tree go to "Certificates (Local Computer) | Personal | Certificates"
8. Find your certificate, right click -> Properties
9. Change **Friendly name** field's value and save

Comment: Will it require a reboot to take effect?

Comment: @jwalker No reboots in my practice -- it's only a name (description) after all.